# S3 partition (file size) for effecient Athena query

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I have a pipeline that load daily records into S3. I then utilize AWS Glue Crawler to create partition for facilitating AWS Athena query. However, there is a large partitioned data, if compared to others.

S3 folders/files are displayed as follows:

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/00/00/2019-00-00.parquet.gzip')   7.8 MB

s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/01/11/2019-01-11.parquet.gzip')  29.8 KB
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/01/12/2019-01-12.parquet.gzip')  28.5 KB
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/01/13/2019-01-13.parquet.gzip')  29.0 KB
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/01/14/2019-01-14.parquet.gzip')  43.3 KB
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket', key='database/table/2019/01/15/2019-01-15.parquet.gzip') 139.9 KB
```

with the file size displayed at the end of each line. Note that, `2019-00-00.parquet.gzip` contains all records before 2019-01-11 and therefore, its size is large. I have read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/) and it says that *"If your data is heavily skewed to one partition value, and most queries use that value, then the overhead may wipe out the initial benefit."*

So, I wonder should I split `2019-00-00.parquet.gzip` into smaller parquet files with different partitions. For example,

```
key='database/table/2019/00/00/2019-00-01.parquet.gzip',
key='database/table/2019/00/00/2019-00-02.parquet.gzip',
key='database/table/2019/00/00/2019-00-03.parquet.gzip', ......
```

However, I suppose this partitioning is not so useful as it does not reflect when were the old records stored. I am opened for all workarounds. Thank you.

Comment: If the file size you are showing are real, then you should not care about low performance. BTW that's really easy to test but again, I doubt you will notice some difference due the size of the files.

Comment: @Roberto Sorry to get back to you this late. Yea, the file size is real. Do you mind to share ways to test even it might be difficult to notice the differences? I am really new to this. Also, from your experience, do you think this is a good way to store `parquet.gzip` files?

Comment: Hi, just make copies of your biggest parquet file (the one with 139.9KB) and save them in the same partition to make the difference between partitions even bigger and test few queries, check timing, remove the copies and test again.
Now, in terms of ways of partitioning parquet files, it depends much of your use case. There is no a best way, just the right way for each case. In terms of compressing, parquet by default is already GZIP compressed internally, but if Glue does that job for you, then I won't complain :)

Answer (score 7):

If the full size of your data is less than a couple of gigabytes in total, you don't need to partition your table at all. Partitioning small datasets hurt performance much more than it helps. Keep all the files in the same directory, deep directory structures in unpartitioned tables also hurt performance.

For small datasets you'll be better off without partitioning as long as there aren't too many files (try to keep it below a hundred). If you for some reason must have lots of small files you might get benefits from partitioning, but benchmark it in that case.

When the size of the data is small, like in your case, the overhead of finding the files on S3, opening, and reading them will be higher than actually processing them.

If your data grows to hundreds of megabytes you can start thinking about partitioning, and aim for a partitioning scheme where partitions are around a hundred megabytes to a gigabyte in size. If there is a time component to your data, which there seems to be in your case, time is the best thing to partition on. Start by looking at using year as partition key, then month, and so on. Exactly how to partition your data depends on the query patterns, of course.